# How to write nested query?

Tags: oracle

I need to display the count of present status for a particular name

```
Select count(*) from employees where status='Present';
```

This query returns me entire present count. What should I do to get status for a particular name?

Comment: for the question you ask to all the comments in all answers, you should start to see some SQL tutorials, try this first: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp - Ahhh, and keep in mind that SQL is not Microsoft SQL, SQL is a database query language!

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this?

```
select status, count(*)
from   employees
group by status
```

Or

```
select name, count(*)
from   employees
where status = 'Present'
group by name
```

Comment: if i have a name abc in database for that name how can i get the count

Comment: just add to the `WHERE` clause your name, like `WHERE name = 'abc'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select name, count(*)
  from employees
  where name = 'abc' and
        status = 'Present';
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score -1):

select count(1) from employees where status='Present' group by name